# Fluid velocity in a vertical pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

Consider a pipe with length $L$ and uniform radius $A$ is held vertically. According to the continuity equation, the velocity of water going into the pipe seems to be the same as the velocity of water coming out. But according to Bernoulli's equation:
$$P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2+\rho gL=P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2$$
$$v_2=\sqrt{v_1^2+2gL}$$
Which means that the water would come out faster, which doesn't make much sense. What is wrong with my equations?

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* have the same pressure at both ends of the pipe. The two velocities *must* be the same (assuming constant pipe diameter) due to mass conservation, so you'll have just the hydrostatic equation, $$p_2-p_1=\rho\,g\,L.$$ Note that your use of the Bernoulli equation for this problem implies that the flow is assumed to be ideal, with no friction. Also notice that the velocity in this problem remains indeterminate.

Comment: It could be fed at atmospheric pressure and be open to air at the bottom.  My answer addresses how that works with continuity.  This answer does explain the potential other interpretitation.

Comment: @JMac No, it could not. Continuity *requires* that the velocities be the same everywhere in the pipe if the pipe has constant diameter as assumed in the OP. The Bernoulli equation then *requires* there to be a pressure increase top to bottom.

Comment: The pipe has constant diameter; but there is nowhere that says the fluid must fill the pipe the entire time.  Like I said, it's a different interpretation of the question.  They don't specify if both ends are open or part of a closed in system; so we can't say for sure that it wont be atmospheric pressure on both ends.  Realistically if there weren't a high enough pressure difference to account for the gravitational change the stream could thin itself down as it gains speed through the pipe.

Comment: @JMac No, this won't happen. Feel free to perform an experiment with a straw...

Comment: can you explain what would stop the water from thinning out as it gained velocity if both ends were open to atmosphere?

Comment: I strongly recommend you just perform the experiment: Fill a straw with water (e.g. by sucking water in), and then close the top of the straw with your finger. What happens? Do you observe the water "thinning out"?

Comment: If you close the top of the straw it's no longer atmospheric pressure on both ends.  Both ends exposed to atmospheric pressure would be like holding the straw in the air and passing a stream of water through it.  You wouldn't want to cover the top of the straw, then it's pressure isn't atmospheric, it's trying to create a vacuum which would effect the pressure difference over the pipe.  If they are both open to atmosphere is is closer to how a faucet works, and you can't tell me that those streams don't thin out.

Comment: The first part of your comment is accurate, and is exactly what I was getting at. Your last sentence talks about a free jet, which is  *not* what we are talking about.

Comment: This question is ambiguous and doesn't make it clear which situation we are talking about.  The question asker was considering it to be Patm on both sides.  I interpreted that as information he had, while you interpreted it as a mistake he made.  Those two situations lead to two different scenarios.  You can have a pipe of fixed diameter with atmospheric pressure on both sides with fluid increasing velocity.  In that case the fluid will just begin to stretch out and take up less than the area of the pipe.  That is what my answer addressed.

Comment: No, you cannot have such a pipe (with $p_{atm}$ at both ends), *if the pipe has constant diameter*. We have just gone over this above. Your "stretching out" scenario is fantasy, and does not happen in the real world.

Comment: @Pirx: nope, not fantasy at all. Although *stretching out* is an awkward term. The loquid would simply not occupy the entire cross-section of the pipe anymore and the bottom end would be in free fall (ignoring friction of course). Try it with a garden hose e.g.: even with one finger on the top, water will still flow out of the bottom.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I don't have any more time to waste on this. We have already discussed the straw experiment. Your water hose will give the exact same result, *if the hose is vertical*. If the hose is lying on the ground at some incline, then the story is very different. The effects at play in this case have nothing to do with the original question and their discussion therefore does not belong here.

Comment: @Pirx Pipe diameter does not explicitly dictate the minimum cross section of the stream, only the maximum.  If a pipe is open on the bottom there is nothing stopping air from being in the pipe and filling the spaces where the liquid no longer flows.  Even playing around with straws I found it was prone to let out less then it seemed I was putting in; but that's also extremely hard to accurately test I found.  You still have offered no reason why this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @ JMac Yes there is: It's called "surface tension". Besides, you have done the experiment, presumably, so you know the answer. The idea that "it was prone to let out less then it seemed I was putting in" obviously makes no sense, since it would violate continuity. Where would the stuff go that you "put in", if it "let out less"?

Answer (score 1):

The diameter of the pipe is likely included to mislead you.

Obviously the fluid should gain speed, but what's also obvious is that it can't increase in mass, and it shouldn't expand since water is basically incompressible.

I had to picture a stream of water allowed to pour freely.  What will happen is that the stream diameter will become smaller to account for the faster velocity.  If the water were a bar of elastic material this would be the same as stretching it.  It's mass flow is the same, it just elongates as it becomes faster.  By the time it reaches the bottom of the vertical pipe the stream will not have a diameter of A.

Comment: +1 Your proposed solution is a possible one. In fact I have witnessed it in a vertical drainage pipe that lets out rain water from the roof, nearby my laboratory.

Comment: Basically, the water in the pipe goes into free fall.  It is accelerating.  To maintain continuity, the cross-section of flow will decrease.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Bernoulli's equation only applies to steady flow -ie. to motion in which the velocity at any point is indepenedent of time. In the case of your pipe open at both ends the fluid will accelerate. In that case you must use the time-dependent version of Bernoulli. For the irrotational flow of in incompressible fluid (so that we can write ${\bf v}=\nabla \phi$) Bernoulli says that
$$
\frac 12 |{\bf v}|^2 + \frac{P}{\rho} +\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}= const.
$$ 
You are omitting the  $\partial \phi/\partial t$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two very large (the liquid levels don't vary), very shallow (hydrostatic pressure is negligible at entrance and outlet) reservoirs, connected by a vertical pipe:

[image: Two connected reservoirs]

It's very tempting to apply Bernoulli here but as the OP observed that would violate the continuity equation.

In reality:

$$P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2+\rho gL=P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2,$$

is not applicable here because **it neglects the resistance to flow** (viscous drag) exerted by the pipe. In reality $v_1=v_2$ and we need to introduce a *head loss* term $\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}$:

$$P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2+\rho gL=P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 +\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}$$

Or:

$$\rho gL=\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}$$

In the case of *laminar flow* through the pipe the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#Pressure-loss_form) can be used to calculate $\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}$:

$$\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}=f_{D}\frac{\rho}{2}\frac{v_1^2}{D}L$$

So that $v_1$ is not indeterminate.

[For turbulent flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#Turbulent_regime) the calculation of $\Delta P_{\mathrm{friction}}$ is more complex.

Comment: it should be possible to satisfy energy equation and continuity without friction

Comment: This is not correct: It does not matter how shallow your top reservoir is. Within the confines of the simplifying assumptions made here, the pressure at the pipe entrance *cannot* be equal to $p_{atm}$. If you apply the Bernoulli equation to a streamline somewhere on the surface of the reservoir where we can assume the velocity to vanish, we can immediately see that the pressure at the pipe entrance will have dropped by $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$. @John Steed is right, of course.

Comment: I note that the situation described by @Gert is a standard undergraduate fluid mechanics problem. The solution (for inifinitely shallow top reservoir and no friction) is simply a flow velocity of $v=\sqrt{2\rho\,g\,L}$, and the pressure at the pipe entrance is $p_e=p_{atm}-\rho\,g\,L$. If $p_e$ drops too low, interesting things (such as cavitation) will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Following the schematics offered by Gert, you have to consider two stages of water flow:

1 - First stage while water flow velocity goes from zero to a certain max that with acceptable negligencies is given by gravity laws. Max velocity magnitude is function of the pipe length...

2 Second stage stable velocity stage if the water  level of the feeding and hosting reservoirs remains constant or such fluctuations should be considered. Bernoulli equation applies considering also head losses from first entrance and length losses.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a vertical pipe connected to a shallow reservoir:

There are mainly 3 points of interest:

1. The outlet of the vertical pipe:

   The heads are:
   $P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}ρv^2$
2. The inlet of the vertical pipe:

   By continuity, the stream has same velocity at inlet and outlet

   $P_{in}+\frac{1}{2}ρv^2 + ρgL = P_{atm}+\frac{1}{2}ρv^2$

   $P_{in} = P_{atm} - ρgL$
3. At the surface of the reservoir:

   $P_{atm} + ρgL = P_{in} + \frac{1}{2}ρv^2 + ρgL $

   $v = \sqrt{2gL}$

   which is the text book answer of Torricelli's law
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law

The principle behind Bernoulli's equation is conservation of energy. The problem can be understood this way:

On water surface of the reservoir, the velocity is zero, but when water is entering the pipe, it gains velocity. Since there is no change in elevation in a shallow reservoir, energy must be converted from pressure head to kinetic head.

As water travels along the pipe, the elevation head decreases but the kinetic head has to remain unchanged due to continuity, so energy is converted from elevation head to pressure head.